# Ninject is finding multiple bindings for implicit self bindings after upgrade to ReactiveUI 7.2

Tags: c#, ninject, reactiveui

I have factory binding injected via [Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject) on an object like so.

```
[Inject]
public Func<TNewDocument> DocumentFactory { get; set; }
```

We call it like

```
var newDoc = DocumentFactory()
```

The first call to DocumentFactory() succeeds.

Subsequent calls result in Ninject reporting that there are multiple bindings for `TNewDocument` at the point of activation.

[image]

I modified my code to call the kernel directly instead of using the factory. I did

```
var docs Kernel.GetAll<TNewDocument>().ToList();
if(docs.Count!=1){
    Console.WriteLine("boo");
}
return docs[0]; // A work around to stop the app crashing
```

I check the number of objects actually returned from the `GetAll` call. This number goes up for every call to create a new object.

The first time one object is returned. The second time two objects, the third time three and so on.

We git bisected the repository to discover the breaking change. It was  an upgrade from [ReactiveUI 7.1 to 7.2](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI). There were no other code changes other than the changes made by nuget.

However ReactiveUI only has a basic relationship to Ninject. I have to provide a service locator to RxUI as below.

```
var customResolver = new FuncDependencyResolver(
    (service, contract) =>
    {
        if (contract != null) return kernel.GetAll(service, contract);
        var items = kernel.GetAll(service);
        var list = items.ToList();
        return list;
    },
    (factory, service, contract) =>
    {
        var binding = kernel.Bind(service).ToMethod(_ => factory());
        if (contract != null) binding.Named(contract);
    });

Locator.Current = customResolver;
```

Other than that [there is no relation](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/search?q=Ninject&type=Commits&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

I can't see why upgrading RxUI should cause this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug/breaking change in ReactiveUI introduced in the latest version.

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/pull/1282

I overrode the default ReactiveUI View Locator with

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Due to bugs / magic in the ReactiveUI view locator we write our own.
    /// The ReactiveUI view locator causes errors if the ViewModel name
    /// doesn't end with "ViewModel". It ends up thinking the ViewModel
    /// and the View are the same class and then very bad stuff happens.
    /// </summary>
    public class WeinCadViewLocator : IViewLocator
    {
        private readonly IKernel _Kernel;

        public WeinCadViewLocator(IKernel kernel)
        {
            _Kernel = kernel;
        }

        public IViewFor ResolveView<T>(T viewModel, string contract = null) where T : class
        {
            Type generic = typeof(IViewFor<>);
            Type[] args = new[] {viewModel.GetType()};
            var realType = generic.MakeGenericType( args );

            if (contract == null)
            {
                return (IViewFor) _Kernel.Get( realType );

            }
            else
            {
                return (IViewFor) _Kernel.Get( realType, contract );
            }

        }
    }
```

and the initialization is now

```
    public static void Init(IKernel kernel)
    {
        var customResolver = new FuncDependencyResolver
            (
             (service, contract) =>
             {
                 if (contract != null)
                     return kernel.GetAll( service, contract );
                 var items = kernel.GetAll( service );
                 var list = items.ToList();
                 return list;
             }
             , (factory, service, contract) =>
             {
                 var binding = kernel
                      .Bind( service )
                      .ToMethod( _ => factory() );
                 if (contract != null)
                     binding.Named( contract );
             } );


        Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeSplat();
        Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeReactiveUI();
        Locator.CurrentMutable = customResolver;
        Locator.CurrentMutable
            .RegisterLazySingleton
              (() => new WeinCadViewLocator(kernel)
              , typeof(IViewLocator));

        var log = SerilogExtensions.DefaultLogger;
        Log.Logger = log;
        SerilogSplatLogger.Register(log);
    }
```